# Unable to load msvcr90.dll from local path

Tags: visual-c++, loadlibrary

I am trying to build a sample Win32 Exe Application in which I am loading msvcr90.dll from C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\ folder. But it is throwing error.
My purpose is to load msvcr90.dll from application's path instead of C:\Windows\WinSxS folder. But not able to do so.

Code snippet:-

```
int APIENTRY _tWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);

    // TODO: Place code here.
    MSG msg;
    HACCEL hAccelTable;

    // Initialize global strings
    LoadString(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadString(hInstance, IDC_DEMO_LOAD_EXE, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);

    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    DWORD dwError = 0;
    SetLastError(dwError);
    LoadLibrary(L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\<myApp>\\<myApp1>\\msvcr90.dll");
    dwError = GetLastError();


    hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_DEMO_LOAD_EXE));

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return (int) msg.wParam;
}
```

In dwError I am getting 126 error

Comment: Windows error code 126 == `ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND` (module not found). Are you sure you have the DLL in the correct location? Also, it's unclear why you would manually distribute the MSVC runtime DLL only, instead of the MSVC runtime redistributable package.

Comment: Yes the path is correct. The reason for using the Dll from my application's path is, with latest version of dll on Win 10, my application is getting crashed. On same system If I change Registry key to use old version(same version dll is present in my application folder), then my application works fine. So just want to load dll from my application's path instead of WinSxS folder.